# add a nested key value pair to a Javascript object where key is dynamic

Tags: javascript

I am writing a validation method to make sure the required nested keys are present in `data` before calling another method that performs calculations using the `data` object.  Here is the code thus far for the validation method -

```
function checkInputDataForMissingNestedKeys(data) {
  const parentKeys = [
    'initialDistance',
    'finalDistance'
  ];

  const nestedKeys = [
    'value',
    'uom'
  ];

  let result = {};

  // if parentKey exists in data, then check for nestedKeys
  parentKeys.forEach(function(entry) {
    if(data[entry] !== undefined) {
      let i = 0;
      nestedKeys.forEach(function(element) {
        if(data[entry][element] === undefined) result[entry][i++] = element;
      })
    }
  });

  return (result.constructor === Object && Object.entries(result).length === 0) ? result : { "missing nested keys": result };
}
```

As written, an error is being encountered: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result[entry][i++] = element')".  I think it's broken due to `result[entry][i++] = element;` because when that part is changed to `result[i++] = element;` then the error goes away BUT overwriting of results occurs.

For testing purposes `data['initialDistance']` and `data['finalDistance`] are both missing the nested key `uom` so the desired result of this, if outputted to the console (the formatting may not be flawless because it was written manually), is -

```
Object {
  "missing nested keys": Object {
     "initialDistance": Object {
        "0": "uom"
      },
     "finalDistance": Object {
        "0": "uom"
      },
   }
}
```

When `result[i++] = element;` is plugged in for experimentation then the console output looks like this (here again, typed out manually) -

```
Object {
  "missing nested keys": Object {
    "0": "uom"
  }    
}
```

What needs to be changed so that `"missing nested keys"` includes the values from `entry`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work.  The logic within `nestedKeys.forEach` needed to be modified to define `result[entry]` as an object before anything could be added to it.  Here is the looping part of the code with the update -

```
  parentKeys.forEach(function(entry) { 
    if(data[entry] !== undefined) {
      let i = 0;
      nestedKeys.forEach(function(element) {
        if(data[entry][element] === undefined) {
          if(result[entry] === undefined) result[entry] = {};
          result[entry][i++] = element;
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget your i variable. This is tripping you up

parentKeys.forEach(function(entry) {
    if(data[entry] !== undefined) {

```
  nestedKeys.forEach(function(element) {
    if(data[entry][element] === undefined) data[entry][element] = "";
  })
}
```

});

Comment: I copied/pasted the code provided but `result` isn't being set to anything now so no validation issues are being outputted.